# Vote for a logo design!

Tags: discussion

As you may have seen if you were present in [The Bakery](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery), we have been blessed with a great designer willing to create a logo.

The following are the prototype designs that [Ronan Forman](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/756/ronan-forman) of *[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour)* has created. Please vote for your favorite, and we will kindly ask him to create a finished version.

This *may* be the logo used on the official site (depending on if the higher-ups like it or not (also legal things)), so choose wisely :).

These are not the actual designs (or drafts of the actual designs), so quality should improve; you're voting on the concepts.

Comment: Is there any word on whether we can use the *actual* Raspberry Pi logo? This is my preference.

Comment: @MarkIngram We cannot use the actual Raspberry Pi Logo: http://www.raspberrypi.org/trademark-rules

Comment: @Jivings Is there a chance I can submit an idea I had? I came up with a rough sketch in Inkscape and was hoping to submit it to the [original question](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-should-the-logo-look-like). Then I saw this one and it looks like the competition is already started.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Suuure. Go for it! :)

Comment: Cool. I will post the rough draft(s) and keep working on refining it.

Comment: question - what about a colour scheme? - a basic design for logo could be found fairly easily, but the colours of the logo sort of depends on the colour of the site background, title, etc.... Pretty cool designs though :)

Answer (score 28):

The logo should be simple, scalable, easy to remember, and it should remind of something related to the Raspberry Pi (small computers, raspberries, easy hacking ...). How about this mashup with the USB trident symbol (which can be used freely in contrast to the trademarked USB logos)? The symbol should be know to mean "easy pluggable computer device" also for non-technical people:

[image: Small]
[image: Large]
[image]

I am not sure about the best orientation. You can get the [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) file to play around with at https://gist.github.com/3748136 Feel free to modify and comment!

Comment: I like this one - but the it lacks the nice '3d' effect of the official Raspberry Pi logo (ie, on this one - the bits of the berry round the side are the same size as the middle). I see you have posted the actual SVG of this (nice) - but my SVG skills are not up to making this modification myself!)

Answer (score 21):

[image: Logo 3]

A pie with a raspberry image on top. The size of the slice can vary.

Comment: The slice could be π. ie. half a pie

Comment: That could work really well: split it vertically and the semicircle would fit really well next to the site title.

Answer (score 19):

[image: Logo 4]

[Tux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux) (the Linux penguin) holding a raspberry.

Comment: Perhaps it could me made clearer that the creature is the linux penguin? (I didn't get it at first)

Comment: @ACarter If you don't feel like it's clear enough, feel free not to vote for it.

Comment: I do like it, it could just be made clearer.

Comment: @ACarter This is just a prototype. The final version would be bells and whistles.

Comment: Is that a bookbag on it?

Comment: @Jivings, I know...

Comment: @Bryan It's the stalk of the fruit.

Comment: @RonanForman Ah. I see it now! =D

Comment: The winglike bulge is quite iffy =/

Comment: Wouldn't this be weird for users new to Linux? The main goal of the Raspberry Pi is to introduce students to it, and these students do not know what Linux is.

Comment: Love the concept, but think this would be better suited to a Linux distribution rather than a Pi... While most Pi's are currently running Linux, don't forget that there may be some now or in the future with other operating systems on (such as RISC OS)

Answer (score 16):

Here's another rough concept:

[image: π Tables!]

And a more [π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi)-like version:

[image: More π-like]

Playing off the π idea, but with no pie.

Comment: We do have to be careful about getting too close to the Raspberry Pi logo (which is trademarked).  Keep in mind when voting for this one that the raspberry will have to look completely different.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Logo 1]

A slice of pie with a raspberry next to it. The location is negotiable.

Comment: I feel like this doesn't convey what the RPi is, integration of Tux (the linux penguin), a chip, π, etc. would improve this

Comment: Perhaps the raspberry can be on the top near the crust, with the π symbol being where the current raspberry is

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX It's just a logo, Arqade has a spaceship, SO has a box with some rectangles in and SE is a speech bubble. We're not playing pictionary here.

Comment: It's often times the one thing people will see, and should be descriptive appropriately

Comment: Is the size of the raspberry negotiable also? ... I'd love it to be bigger. `$0.02`

Comment: i would suggest for this illustration that the pies content is some kind of circuit and the raspberry sits on top of the widest part of the pi.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Logo 5]

A pie made to look like the chip board for the actual Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Logo 2]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Logo 10]

The [Hacker Emblem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_Emblem) with raspberries in the [alive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) states.

Answer (score 8):

How about a similar shape to the current (default) logo, a square with rounded edges and a triangle coming out of the bottom, but replacing said square with a simple vector graphic of the new A+?

[image: Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange draft]

Comment: Nice! Looks real good.

Answer (score 7):

It's a simplistic logo, similar to *[Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)*'s logo.

It uses the open font [Quicksand](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand), which is the same on the [Raspberry Pi Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Foundation) uses.

**Version 1:** - Simplest version, no extra stuff

[image: 256x256 version1]

**Version 2:** - Slightly more complex, and it looks a bit more like the Raspberry Pi. Also isn't *quite* square.

[image: 2nd version]

Obviously, these are still needing some work.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Logo 11]

A pie with a pi on top, made by Jin.

Comment: Thanks for posting this ronan. this is just a concept, pay no attention to graphic details. The concept is a Pie, with a Pi cut.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Logo 6]

A pie with a slice missing and a raspberry on top.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Logo 7]

*Raspberry .14* (pi is 3.14 for those non-maths-y people)

This also ties in with [Element **14**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element14), one of the two Raspberry Pi distributors.

Comment: I quite like the look, but is tying in specifically with one of the distributors really a good thing? It makes it seem like we've got an affiliation we haven't.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Logo 9]

A pie with some wires coming out of it.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Logo 8]

A pi symbol with some raspberries around the place.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Honeycomb concept... Things like font and colors can vary

Comment: I really like the idea of this, and it could be easily combined with some of the other ideas, such as taking a 60 degree slice out of it.

Comment: @MarkBooth I think I got in too late for it to pass

Comment: I like this. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of fleshed out ideas based on the top answer, made in [Paint.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint.NET):

[image]

And a cropped version for a more squarish icon; this might fit better on the title bar.

[image]