# How can I help the web site?

Tags: discussion

I am a capable graphic designer (but with limited creativity :/) and I'd love to help bring peoples design ideas about the site to life. How can I help?

*I'm putting extra emphasis on the "limited creativity" part, I don't have any awesome ideas, but I sure can bring others to life*

Answer (score 3):

Great! There's plenty of interesting work to be done. Currently we're looking for a designer to help us with our community advert.

Firstly we're [choosing a logo](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/vote-for-a-logo-design) and then we shall be mocking up the advert itself. Head over to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery) for more discussion.

Comment: Did anything ever come of the logo vote?